# how to create unit test cases for kotlin data classes

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit4, data-class

I have created few data classes for my sample application. I need to write unit test cases for those data classes now. I am using Junit4.12. Here is my data class:

```
data class Tracking(val  param1 : String?=null, val  param2 : String?=null, val param3 : String?=null){}
```

I tried writing one basic unit test case for this model like below:

```
@Test
    fun tracking()
    {
        val trackingData= Tracking("7030054",
        "skdfksbfbkjsdf",
        "dfkhsbfsjf")
        Assert.assertEquals("true",trackingData.param1,"7030054")
    }
```

But i don't see it is right way of performing a unit test case. My Objective for unit test case is to assert an exception if user sends null value as an input. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are all String?, so nullable. If you want them to always be non-null, use String instead. Then you don't need a unit-test since non-nullability will be checked by the compiler.

If they can sometimes be null but not always, you have to first write a function that checks that condition.
A very simple example would be something like

```
fun simpleValidation() {
  if(param1 == null) {
    throw RuntimeException("Should not be null")
  }
}
```

in the class tracking.
You can than unit test this by

```
@Test
    fun tracking()
    {
        val trackingData= Tracking(null,
        "skdfksbfbkjsdf",
        "dfkhsbfsjf")
        Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException::class.java) { trackingData.simpleValidation() }
    }
```

assuming you are using JUnit5